# How can I make a program to operate another program?

Tags: bots

So what I'm wanting to do is pretty lame. Anyway, what I'm wanting to do is basically make a bot that will do some specified tasks for me.

I have an emulator on my laptop that when open, operates like an Android phone, and I'm using Snapchat on it. What I have been trying to do is make it send my 'streaks' on Snapchat a picture everyday at specified times. I have tried using a Macro Recorder to do this, but the loading time varies.

My questions are:

1) What programming language should I use for this?

2) What would be the best application to use? (Like Notepad, or some other application)

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of autohotkey (AHK)? It's a macro app, but also a very powerful programming language. Entire apps have been written in it.

You can also use it to control other programs.

reference:

http://ahkscript.org/

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks for the response!